# Python: Sum of numbers

Tags: python, list, sum

In my program I have this:

```
decrypt=input("Please enter the key you used to encrypt the above text: ")
key="".join(map(str,[ord(d) for d in decrypt]))
print(key)
```

This prints according to the input, but for example mine would be:

```
1207356100604112383
```

But I need it be like this:

```
[120, 73, 56, 100, 60, 41, 123, 83]
```

How do I get it to be like that?

Once that is done I need the program to add those together, divide the result by 8, round down to a whole number and then subtract 32.

Comment: why are you joining when you want to print a list and you have that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `join`. Print the `map` object using `list`

```
>>> decrypt=input("Please enter the key you used to encrypt the above text: ")
Please enter the key you used to encrypt the above text: hello
>>> key=(map(str,[ord(d) for d in decrypt]))
>>> print(list(map(int,key)))
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

A better way would be to leave the list comprehension as such

```
>>> key = [ord(d) for d in decrypt]
>>> print(key)
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

In this way you don't need to use any of the `map`, `str` call, etc.

---

For your example

```
>>> decrypt=input("Please enter the key you used to encrypt the above text: ")
Please enter the key you used to encrypt the above text: xI8d<){S
>>> key = [ord(d) for d in decrypt]
>>> key
[120, 73, 56, 100, 60, 41, 123, 83]
```

or if you insist on `map`

```
>>> key = map(ord,decrypt)
>>> print(list(key))
[120, 73, 56, 100, 60, 41, 123, 83]
```